# trying to install pcfDev on macbook , get error -Pivotal Network returned: 403 Forbidden

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to install PCF dev and when i put in my API token I get 403 Forbidden error

cf dev start
Less than 4096 MB of free memory detected, continue (y/N): > y
Please retrieve your Pivotal Network API from:
https://network.pivotal.io/users/dashboard/edit-profile

API token> 
FAILED

Error: Pivotal Network returned: 403 Forbidden.

I can do >> curl https://network.pivotal.io

without errors

I have cf cli installed

cf version 6.21.1+6fd3c9f-2016-08-10

Also have Oracle Virtual box

5.1.4r110228

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried a few other things but kept getting the same error. I thought I am typing or copy pasting the wrong api token - when i deliberately typed out a wrong api token to test this theory - i actually got wrong api token error. 
Then I had a hunch that there's something wrong with my pivotal account itself, so i created another one with another email id and tried again and it worked..

so that was the problem..